# Fancybox перестает работать после того как картинки пришли аяксом

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть галлерея изображений, и после того как она через аякс обновилась, фэнси не срабатывает на изображения.
Вот вызов фэнси

```
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        return '';
    }
});
```

И еще как можно поставить таймаут на .get()?
Пример:

```
    $.get(ajaxUrl, {}, function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
```

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под  "поставить таймаут на .get()"

Comment: чтобы гет запрашивался после спустя определенное временя

Comment: Так, не?
   setTimeout(function (){
      $.get(...);
   }, 350); // время в mSec

Comment: Так, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$.initFancyBox = function (el, sel){
   sel = sel || 'a[rel="example_group"]';
   $(sel, el).fancybox({
       transitionIn:  'none',
       transitionOut: 'none',
       titlePosition: 'over',
       titleFormat:   function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts){
           return '';
       }
   });
};

$(document)
    .ready(function (){ $.initFancyBox('#content'); })
    .ajaxSuccess(function() { $.initFancyBox('#content'); })
;
```

Comment: Еще перестает работать кнопка после аякса :)
Пытался прилепить к ней on(), но что-то делаю не так

$('#drop a').on("click", (function(e){
    // Имитация клика по input
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    $.get('/algo/get/get_user_photos.php', {}, function(data){
        $('.photo_user_list').html(data);
    });
}));

Comment: Если drop не находиться в #content, то можно так:

   $('#drop').on('click', 'a', function (evt){ });

Answer (score 0):

После получения картинок, заного поставьте им fancybox